# Play Video with Full Screen in VidoView in android

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am going to show the video in full screen in android in **VideoView**, but its not going to display in full screen.

My code for displaying video is:

```
 <VideoView android:id="@+id/myvideoview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</VideoView>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Below code is working in my case:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent" >
   <VideoView android:id="@+id/myvideoview"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </VideoView>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you mean my full screen? Sometime you may expect hide activity action bar and all. If so add following code at run time.

```
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i got my answer at this link [Play video in Full Screen](http://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2014/02/18/showing-fullscreen-video-in-android/). When we want to play video in full screen, then just add these line of code in your Androidmanifest.xml file, in the activity where this video is going to play. Just add these two lines in android manifest file , like

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" 
 android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Like in my androidmanifest.xml file i have added it

```
  <activity
        android:name="com.appliconic.straminglivevideo.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```